# Number of linearly independent eigenvectors of expression of a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $M$ be a $3\times3$ singular matrix and suppose that $2$ and $3$ are eigenvalues of $M$. Then what is the number of linearly independent eigenvectors of $M^3+2M+I_3$?

These are my attempts, one of which saw light:

**Attempt #1**: Given eigenvalues are $2,3 (\text{and }0)$. Then  $M$ gives $(M-2I)(M-3I)M=M^3-5M^2+6M=0\implies M^3+2M+I=5M^2-4M+I$, and I think I hit a roadblock.

**Attempt #2**: Singular $\implies 0$ is an eigenvalue, so if I consider $M=\text{diag}(2,3,0)$, I get $A=M^3+2M+I_3=\text{diag}(13,34,1)$, and since it has distinct eigenvalues, I concluded that the answer is 3.

My question is:

Is there anyway to come to a conclusion proceeding in lines of arguments in attempt #1? I will also be grateful if someone can point out any other useful facts that will further simplify/a simpler solution than attempt #2!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are similar matrices, and $P$ is a polynomial, then $P(M)$ and $P(N)$ are similar. This is useful when you want to know about $P(M)$, and you've found a simple matrix $N$ that is similar to $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that $M$ need not be a diagonal matrix (as you have stated in attempt 2). The best you can say is it will be similar to the diagonal matrix.

I think your attempt no. 1 will not yield information about the eigen vectors because you are trying to compute what that matrix will look like and it will eventually lead to using the eigen values of $M$ to compute the eigen values of the polynomial matrix in $M$, which is essentially what I am providing as my answer.

Let us call $A=M^3+2M+I_3$. If $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $M$, then the eigen values of $A$ wil be $\lambda^3+2\lambda+1$. So keeping in mind that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with three distinct eigen values, it will have three linearly independent eigen vectors.

Comment: thank you! And yes, it need not be diagonal, but I took the freedom since the question suggests that for any such $M$, the "then" part should be same, then it should give me the desired number if I choose any one of such $M$.